# `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` while concatenating list of pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of numpy arrays and I am trying to merge them into a 2d matrix in the following way:

```
[arr1, arr2, arr3....] 

arr1 = [0.24, 0.24, 0.56, 0.77]
arr2 = [0.1, 0.24]
arr3 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.72, 0.88]
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
NaN, 0.24, 0.24, 0.56, Nan, Nan,  Nan, 0.77, Nan
0.1, 0.24,  Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan,  Nan,  Nan, Nan
Nan,  Nan,  Nan, Nan, 0.6, 0.7, 0.72,  NaN, 0.88
```

I use the following script to merge them:

```
# convert to series
series = [pd.Series(arr,index=arr) for arr in arrs]

# concat with reindex
pd.concat(series, axis=1)
```

But I run into the following error:

```
raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Note that the input arrays have duplicates within them and I would like to keep those duplicates.

How do I go about fixing it?

EDIT:

given the discussion in the comments, the error is most likely arising due to duplicates and I was hoping to figure out a workaround that.

Comment: What happened to `0.88`, and what is the logic of placing `0.77` where it is?

Comment: The code should run fine with this data. You have repeated values within on of the arrays. You need to decide what to do in which case.

Comment: You should modify your sample data to show the expected output when there are duplicates, e.g. do you want to drop them or do you want to keep them

Comment: I have modified the sample data and I would like to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround when you have repeated data, namely, to index the series by the value and order of occurrence

```
new_arrs = []
for a in arrs:
    a = pd.Series(a)
    occurrences = a.groupby(a).cumcount()
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((x,y) for x,y in zip(a, occurrences ))
    a.index = idx

    new_arrs.append(a)

pd.concat(new_arrs, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
           0     1     2
0.10 0   NaN  0.10   NaN
0.24 0  0.24  0.24   NaN
     1  0.24   NaN   NaN
0.56 0  0.56   NaN   NaN
0.60 0   NaN   NaN  0.60
0.70 0   NaN   NaN  0.70
0.72 0   NaN   NaN  0.72
0.77 0  0.77   NaN   NaN
0.88 0   NaN   NaN  0.88
```